# Extrair porção de caracteres usando PHP

Tags: php, regex

Olá galera tenho a seguinte string:

```
'<a href="http://localhost/mensageiro/1990/">1990</a>&nbsp;(1)
<a href="http://localhost/mensageiro/1994/">1994</a>&nbsp;(2)
<a href="http://localhost/mensageiro/1995/">1995</a>&nbsp;(4)'
```

Como transformar essa string em um array: `[1990 => 1, 1694 => 2 , 1995 => 4]`

PS: Não precisa postar o código todo. Uma luz de como fazer já vai me ajudar bastante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um jeito simples de fazer é utilizando os métodos [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php) e [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php).

```
function extrair($str) {
  # Extrai o número de dentro da tag a
  preg_match_all("|<[^>]+>(.*)</[^>]+>|", $str, $Keys, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
  # Extrai o número de dentro dos parênteses
  preg_match_all("|\(([\d])\)|", $str, $Values, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
  # Combina os arrays
  return array_combine($Keys[1], $Values[1]);
}
```

O método [`array_combine`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-combine.php) irá combinar o array `$Keys` e o array `$Values`, sendo `$Keys` as chaves e `$Values` os valores, chegando assim ao resultado `[1990 => 1, 1694 => 2 , 1995 => 4]`

> Podes ver funcionando em [repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ProfuseStripedDesignmethod)

Comment: Olha você é bom..Obrigado !

Comment: Sou apenas um aprendiz! **:)**

Answer (score 2):

Espero que o código abaixo lhe ajude amigo!

```
  function apenasNumero($valor)
  {
      $num = preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/is', '', $valor ); //preg_replace( '/[^0-9]/is... retira tudo que não for número
     return $num;
  }

  function resolveProblema($string)
  {
     //iniciando um novo array
     $novo = array();

     //Como vi que todas as linhas terminam com ")"
     $vetor = explode(")",$string); //transformo em um vetor

    //string padrão até encontrar o primeiro número
    $pontos = '<a href="http://localhost/mensageiro/'; //ou seja, a string que eu quero retirar 

     //navegando pelas possições do vetor
     foreach($vetor as $val)
     {
        //retirando string (padrão) do valor
        $result = str_replace($pontos, "", $val);


        $primeiroValor = apenasNumero(substr($result,0,7)); //pagando apenas o valor numérico

        //pegando o valor dos 4 ultimos caracteres da string
        $segundoValor = apenasNumero(substr($result,-4));

        //criando indices do novo vetor
        $novo[$primeiroValor] = $segundoValor;
     }

     // Como sei que a ultima possição do array vem vazio
     array_pop($novo); //elimino a ultima possição

     return $novo;
  }

  //string que vc utilizou no problema
  $string = '<a href="http://localhost/mensageiro/1990/">1990</a> (1)
  <a href="http://localhost/mensageiro/1994/">1994</a> (2)
  <a href="http://localhost/mensageiro/1995/">1995</a> (4)';

 //uso a tag <pre> só para visualizar melhor
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r(resolveProblema($string));
 echo '</pre>';
```